# How to clip text under a section while maintaining the background?

Tags: html, css, background, clip

I have a section that contains a fixed header graphic, some text, and a background.

The behavior I'm trying to accomplish is that when scrolled past, the text section will disappear under the header. However, I need to maintain the background graphic for the section.

I suspect some kind of css clipping to be applied to invisible section, but most searches show how to clip to show the background, and not hide. Maybe some odd parallax behavior?

A quick mockup: Normal(left), Scrolled(right)

[image: Mockup]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overflow: auto` on the content section to get it to "disappear" like that under the header when it's scrolled. Here is a quick demo of how that would work. Note that the gray page background shows through, and an image background would as well.

**Live Demo:**

```css
#header h2 {
    margin: 0;
}

#content {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}

html, body {
    background: #CCCCCC;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"><h2>Header</h2></div>
<div id="content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/wLcmrk9m/1/

Comment: I think this works if I set a content to have a fixed height, and you scroll within the that fixed content. For me, I have a fixed header, then the content being part of the page. So I'm not sure if this going to work out without messing with the rest of the page.

Comment: @Chris In that case, you should just set the same background image on your header and your page content, and use the `background-position` property on one so that they both line up.

Comment: I think that might just work... Not exactly the route I had in mind, but I'll give it try.

Comment: Kinda. I had to implement a parallax effect to keep them synced up. It was decided that the animation need vs the implementation was too complex, I simply put the header above the background area.